# HTML form doesn't reset after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I complete the following **HTML form** in my "main" page(*main.php*):

```
<form action="sessions.php" method="post">
  <input type="" placeholder="Insert Database Name" name="dbName" id="dbName">
  <input type="" placeholder="Insert Server Name" name="serverName" id="serverName">
  <input type="" placeholder="Insert User Name" name="userName" id="userName">

  <button type="submit" name="Submit" id="sub">Connect</button>
</form>
```

When the user presses the "**Submit**" button(I made it to **not refresh** the page), the form data are posted to another page(*sessions.php*):

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $_SESSION['dbName'] = $_POST['dbName'];
  $_SESSION['serverName'] = $_POST['serverName'];
  $_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['userName'];
  $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
?>
```

Then, those data are read from another page(*graphs.php*):

```
<?php 
  session_start();

  $serverName = $_SESSION['serverName'];
  $userName = $_SESSION['userName'];
  $password = $_SESSION['password'];
  $dbName = $_SESSION['dbName'];
?>
```

When I **refresh** the page, the form data are **preserved**.
How to **delete** them after page **refresh**?

Comment: `session_destroy()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "preserved"? In the given code, you don't do anything with these variables

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I want the form data to be preserved until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use [session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) after you have handled the data (stored in database, performed calculation etc.) HTTP is a stateless protocol, so refreshing the page would not update your session variables because it is the PHP server that is handling the session, completly unrelated to a page refresh.

Comment: In the first page(main.php) when I submit the data, a new button appears, and when clicked a new window is opened containing some data from the database(got them from last page(graphs.php)). So, if i use session_destroy(), when that new button is clicked again, nothing will happen(form should be submitted again). I want somehow to preserve the form data and delete them only by page refresh.

Comment: Then use javascript to store the state of the form, and only submit with all the data. Like I said, HTTP is a stateless protocol. There is no way for the PHP server to know when the page was refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

`Hey Try this with the function method above input methods..
create a simple function 
using onclick method in the submit button and put the values=null in side the function
eg.

```
"function clearForm() {
   document.myform.reset();
                   }"
```

But the session_destroy(); for deleting the whole session.
And

"session_unset(); would delete only the variables from session - session still exists. Here  Only data is truncated."

They both are better option.`